# how i can get onActivityResult in fragment from secondActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

from fragment i started FirstActivity  and from FirstActivity i started a SecondActivity.how i can get onActivityResult in fragment from SecondActivity.
I tried to Add android:noHistory="true" in firstActivity.

is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

FragmentActivity

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    hotelImageMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, HotelsByLocation.class);
        intent.putExtra(HotelActivity.EXTRA_PARAM_FOR_RESULT, true);
        intent.putExtra(HotelsByLocation.EXTRA_PARAM_LOCATION_NAME, App.getInstance().getDayList().get(AddHotels.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).get(App.HASHMAP_PARA_CITY_NAME));
        intent.putExtra(HotelsByLocation.EXTRA_PARAM_LOCATION_ID, App.getInstance().getDayList().get(AddHotels.viewPager.getCurrentItem()).get(App.HASHMAP_PARA_CITY_ID));
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE_TWO);
     }
 });


@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE_TWO) {
                  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                      Toast.makeText(myContext, "Welcome Back from HotelsByLocation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                      map.put(App.HASHMAP_PARA_CITY_NAME, data.getStringExtra("cname"));
                      map.put(App.HASHMAP_PARA_CITY_ID, data.getStringExtra("cid"));
                      map.put(App.HASHMAP_PARA_HOTEL_NAME, data.getStringExtra("name"));
                      map.put(App.HASHMAP_PARA_HOTEL_IMAGE, data.getStringExtra("img"));
                      App.getInstance().getDayList().set(AddHotels.viewPager.getCurrentItem(),map);
                      hotel_name_main.setText(data.getStringExtra("name"));
                      Picasso.with(myContext)
                              .load(data.getStringExtra("img"))
                              .error(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                              .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                              .into(hotelImageMain);

      }
      } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
          // some stuff that will happen if there's no result
          Toast.makeText(myContext, "you haven't selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
```

FirstActivity

```
mmAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new HATwo.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);                             
       intent.putExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_PARAM_HOTEL_ID, mPhotosList.get(position).getId());                      
       intent.putExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_PARAM_HOTEL_NAME, mPhotosList.get(position).getTitle());                                    
       intent.putExtra(HotelActivity.EXTRA_PARAM_FOR_RESULT, true);
      //startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE_TWO);
       startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("name",nameOfTheHotel );
    intent.putExtra("id", hotelId);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: so if I understand correctly what you want is some data from your second activity back to the fragment. Right??

Comment: Yes...I want it in onActivityResult to make change in fragment.

Comment: one more thing is there any specific reason you want the result in onActivityResult method of fragment?? When you're going back from Activity2 to your fragment you can easily make necessary changes to your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use startActivity from fragment to firstactivity and then startActivityForResult from firstactivity to secondactivity.  When you get your result from secondactivity you handle it on your firstactivity's onActivityResultResult and use intent to go from firstactivity to the fragment and pass the value obtained from second activity to fragment from firstactivity.  make sure to handle the backstack correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all uncomment that

```
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE_TWO);
```

from `onItemClick` method of `FirstActivity` and comment

```
//startActivity(intent);
```

Add this `onActivityResult` in `FirstActivity`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE_TWO) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("name", data.getExtras().getString("name"));
        intent.putExtra("id", data.getExtras().getString("id"));
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The result of `SecondActivity` will be delivered to `FirstActivity` and the result of `FirstActivity` will be delivered to the `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

pass on activity result value  from activity to fragment by call ->

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and then call on activity result in fragment

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("onF**kingHere*frg", String.valueOf(requestCode) + " " + resultCode);
}
```